# How to call some async code in an ASP.NET application_start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

In our application_startup, we seed up our database with some fake data, if no data exists.

To do this, we're using the `Async` methods to store the data. Great. Only problem is, we're not sure how to do this in the `application_startup` because that's not an async method.

I've spent soooo much time trying to understand @StevenCleary's tutorials and I'm always getting deadlocks. I totally [grok what he consistently says](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html):

> As a general rule, you should use "async all the way down"; that is, don't block on async code

but I just don't get how I can do that, in this case :(

Lets imagine this is the code I'm trying to play with...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var someFakeData = LoadSomeFakeData();
    var documentStore = new DocumentStore();
    await documentStore.InitializeAsync(someFakeData);

    ...

    // Registers this database as a singleton.
    Container.Register(documentStore);
}
```

and later on .. some code that uses this `documentStore`. It is injected via construction injection ...

```
public SomeController(IDocumentStore documentStore)
{
    _documentStore = documentStore;
}

public ViewModel GetFoos()
{
    using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        ... db code goes in here ... 
    }
}
```

#### Clarification

I'm *not* trying to do some async code in here. I'm actually trying to call this async method, *synchronously*. Sure, i loose the benefits of async blah blah de blah.. but i'm happy with that. This is start up and I'm happy to block on startup.

Comment: Why not run this code synchronously instead? Using async IO is all about gaining throughput. This piece of code will run once and only on startup, i don't see the gain. Moreso, you'll have to put in more effort as this startup is completley synchronous. Does your provider have a synchronous API as well?

Comment: You can't really to my knowledge - unlike all request events this one does not have async version... You can use all methods to call async methods synchronously. Maybe lazy initialization on first actual request is an option?

Comment: @Alexi I also thought about that, but i see no actual gain from making it initialize async on the first request. He'll even "lose" for the fact the first request will take longer to execute.

Comment: There is no sync api avail. I understand that what i want to do is blocking. I get that and I'm happy with that -> this is some start up code .. call it once .. and then continue. _I'm not trying to do any async here._ I'm trying to do this as sync .. but don't know how.

Comment: are you using Entity Framework for your data layer ? if so, using Code-first initializers to seed the data will help you achieve seeding your database with your fake data.

Comment: No i'm not - and the database _type_ should not be an issue - this question is agnostic to databases or anything else. It's about calling an async method in this sync code/pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you're asynchronously initializing a shared resource. So, I recommend that you either save the `Task` itself, or introduce an asynchronous wrapper type.

Using `Task`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  var someFakeData = LoadSomeFakeData();
  var documentStore = new DocumentStore();
  var documentStoreTask = documentStore.InitializeAsync(someFakeData);

  ...

  // Registers this database task as a singleton.
  Container.Register(documentStoreTask);
}
```

That may be too awkward, though, depending on `Container`. In that case, you can introduce an asynchronous wrapper type:

```
public sealed class DocumentStoreWrapper
{
  private readonly Task<DocumentStore> _documentStore;

  public DocumentStoreWrapper(Data data)
  {
    _documentStore = CreateDocumentStoreAsync(data);
  }

  private static async Task<DocumentStore> CreateDocumentStoreAsync(Data data)
  {
    var result = new DocumentStore();
    await documentStore.InitializeAsync(data);
    ...
    return result;
  }

  public Task<DocumentStore> DocumentStoreTask { get { return _documentStore; } }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
  var someFakeData = LoadSomeFakeData();
  var documentStoreWrapper = new DocumentStoreWrapper(someFakeData);

  ...

  // Registers this database wrapper as a singleton.
  Container.Register(documentStoreWrapper);
}
```

Or, you could use `AsyncLazy<T>`, which does much the same thing but uses a background thread to execute the initialization code.

Comment: Hi Stephen :) I was _so_ hoping you might find this question and help :) Big thanks! What I don't understand with your answer is that you're still trying to avoid executing the method straight away? With the wrapper, that's still a `Task` that is being registered/remembered. With `AsyncLazy<T>`, that's still a `Task` being registered by it's it's also `Lazy` (which is nice!). But i still have to `await` it at some point? I was just hoping to run my init code, there and then (and yes.. block if i have to which I expect i do). Why can't i just do that - and that works without hanging.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: My solutions do *start* the method immediately. It is only awaited when the *results* are required.

Comment: I guess that's the part I'm really confused with :( :blush: I don't want a result here. I just want the method to execute, then stick the `documentStore` into the container. Looking at the code above, I see that i need to `await` to return the `documentStore` instance? I've updated my OP to show some example code how I use this `documentStore`, later on. I'm so sorry I'm struggle with this, Stephen but I really really do appreciate your kind help !

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Just "lift" the types in question. Instead of injecting a `DocumentStore`, can you inject a `Task<DocumentStore>`? If not, inject a `DocumentStoreWrapper`. Then your consuming code can await it.

Comment: But that's my problem. I don't want to `await` anything else (eg methods or properties) from this instance. The only thing I wish to `await` (or more precisely, `Wait`) is the `InitializeAsync()` which should just happen on startup. Now I also grok the `Lazy` option here ... where the init will occur when the instance is FIRST requested/returned .. but I still don't see how that works here because `AsyncLazy` still returns a `Task` :( I know i really am missing something here, so please bear with me as I try and understand this :/ Please don't give up on me and this question :)

Comment: AFAIK, ASP.NET doesn't provide any way to asynchronously initialize. So your only real options are to either use synchronous methods (and block), or use a task to start the initialization on startup and await it later when you need it. Of the two, I prefer the latter if possible.

Comment: Ok. So there's no way I can tell an async method to run as SYNC (ie. `.Wait()` and block) but not hang?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Not easily. You can run a nested loop (i.e., `AsyncContext`), block (`Wait` plus `ConfigureAwait(false)`), or push it to a background thread (`Task.Run(() => ...).Wait()`), but each of these have problems. There's no universal solution.

Comment: Ah gotcha - this is my huge gripe with async :( Could you update the answer with these options, please sir?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I don't recommend them for your scenario. There's a brief overview [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx), and I'm planning a future blog post on the subject.

Comment: Interesting blog post you linked :) I feel like I'm soooo stuck between a rock and a hardplace. I'm stuck with an async API yet i'm in some sync context so I loose-loose :( So frustrating :/

Comment: That blog post is saying that it was best for the API NOT to make the sync/async decision for you.  I can't tell for sure if that is the case from the example code.  If it is returning a task, then Stephen Cleary and Stephen Toub are pointing you to make the decision to run the code synchronously, which is definitely what you want to do in ASP.NET Application_Start

If InitializeAsync isn't returning a Task, then it sounds like the API DID make the decision for you, and that is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use of `Task.Run(() => YourAsyncMethod());` inside of none async method like:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Task.Run(() => MyAsyncMethod(true));
    }
```

Comment: That should be the best answer. Simple and easy. And works like a charm.

Comment: The OP wanted to run the code synchronously and wait for it to complete. This approach runs the task in parallel via the threadpool. Not quite what he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic, but it's popped up in my search and maybe it will for others.

For what the OP has requested (ie. To run an async method in a synchronous way from inside a synchronous method, and block until it's finished), is there some reason that the use of [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8) would not be a simple and adequate way of addressing this?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Task.WaitAll(MyAsyncMethod(true));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory MyTaskFactory = new
    TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        return MyTaskFactory
          .StartNew(func)
          .Unwrap()
          .GetAwaiter()
          .GetResult();
    }
    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        MyTaskFactory
          .StartNew(func)
          .Unwrap()
          .GetAwaiter()
          .GetResult();
    }
}
```

then use as

```
AsyncHelper.RunSync(ProcessAsync);

private async Task ProcessAsync(){ ....
```

Comment: This code will deadlock under certain circumstances. See Stephen Cleary's postings for details.